# how to create multiple tab activity like in browser android

Tags: android

I want to create an activity with all fragments that are available in the fragment manager just like we have all the tabs in the android browsers in slider form.

Answer (score 0):

Google Android Developers has a nice material for those who want to learn how to develop for Android.

Try to follow this guide, it guide's you how to create a page adapter with fragments and fragment manager, its quite near of what you want.

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral#java